# Selecting distinct values from multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a `mail` table with four columns: `id`, `userto`, `userfrom`, and `message`. I want to receive a list of users that have either sent mail to user "example", and I want to join it with a list of users that user "example" sent mail to. However, I don't want any repeating usernames in this list.

How would I do this? I'm sure it has something to do with `SELECT DISTINCT` and `INNER JOIN`, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with a `UNION`. Your mileage may vary depending on your RDBMS.

```
SELECT userto AS listuser
FROM mail
WHERE userfrom = 'example'
UNION
SELECT userfrom AS listuser
FROM mail
WHERE userto = 'example';
```

Edit:
You don't need to use `SELECT DISTINCT` there, `UNION` will get rid of repetition from within each subquery as well as between the queries.

Comment: it does get rid of reapting values